# Amazon MWS XSD Files

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, amazon-mws

I'm trying to validate my Amazon XML requests against their XSD files. The PDF in the documentation links to most of the XSDs, but there's still quite a few missing, which means that my XSD validation fails.

Some examples of missing XSD files are:

- TypeDefinitions.xsd
- ProductAttributes.xsd
- ListingSummary.xsd
- Offer.xsd

As I say, most are available, but there's some that aren't. Does anyone know if these can be obtained from anywhere?

Comment: I had to edit my main xsd so missing files are not referenced. Now I can at least validate *some* files... very unfortunate.

Comment: @Hazzit Yep, this is what I'm having to do currently. "Unfortunate" is not the word I was thinking of :/

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can get a zip file of the current xsds from Amazon MWS support. Here's the contact link (US accounts): https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/mws/contactus.html

Comment: Thanks - I'll drop them an email tomorrow and let you know what they get back with.